# Unix "find" command usage

Tags: regex, bash, find

This is for a bash installation script. The script foo.sh takes "DIRECTORY" as an argument. Say, there is a dir `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1A/TEST_2A/TEST_3` and another dir `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3`.

Script: foo.sh in brief.

```
DIR='find $HOME -type d -name $1 | head 1'
if [ DIR is set to a directory ]
then
   rm -rf $DIR
fi
exit 0
```

Usage: `foo.sh TEST_3`

Now from the script, only the `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1A/TEST_2A/TEST_3` can be removed. To remove `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3`, I need to use a reg exp in my find command, to fine tune the remove to resolve the directory conflict.

Modified the find part of the above script as below

```
DIR='find $HOME -type d -regexp $1 | head 1'
```

New usage: `foo.sh TEST_2B/TEST_3`

But "find" command FAILS to get the `DIR` set to `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3` and instead returns empty & as a result `DIR` is empty and I can never ever remove `<$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3`

How do I change the script, so that find can act on JUST the directory name, as well as on the path to the directory too with NO issues. Infact, some users may give a partial directory path as argument to "foo.sh". I expect "foo.sh" to work, even in such cases

Comment: Please post the source for the bash script. I've written tons of fairly elementary, albeit long scripts. Nothing helps like echo-ing your arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
if [[ "$1" == */* ]]; then
    EXPR="-path *$1"
else
    EXPR="-name $1"
fi
DIR=$(find $HOME -type d $EXPR | head -1)
```

A simple name like "TEST_3" will translate into `find -name TEST_3` but a name with a slash like "ST_2/TEST_3" will translate into `find -path *ST_2/TEST3`. This will take care of (partial) directory names.

Comment: I have a problem with find here. I think "find" has an issue with partial path. For ex, find $(HOME) -path *ST_2B/TEST_3 works, but find $(HOME) -path TEST_2B/TEST_3, yields nothing. Strange. I have to support partial paths too, with "find" resolving the path and then removing it

Comment: @Mike: Find does not have an issue, only your expectations are wrong. `-path` compared the _complete_ path to the given pattern. Therefore a `xyz/TEST_2B/TEST_3` is compared to your argument `TEST_2B/TEST3` which obviously is a no-match. Compared to `*/TEST_2B/TEST_3` it _IS_ a match. Regarding "partial match": If my answer is not what you want, please clarify this in the question by editing it. Long discussion within an answer are frowned upon - see the FAQ for this.

Comment: With your second explanation, I got what -path expects & it will work for me. THANKS A LOT

Comment: You are welcome. Please lookup http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask howto vote on and accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work as intended?

```
find $HOME -type d -name $1 -exec echo {} ';'  -exec rm -rf {} ';'
```

It will complain about deleting of processed directory, but toher than some stderr output it's ok...

You can ofc change "-name" for "-regexp" as you suggested, but if you want something more complex, you can create special script to call from "-exec"

EDIT:
I probably understood you wrong first time (but won't delete anything, it may help somebody) - you want to delete only one of TEST_3 directories (how do you choose which one? first found by find? - it seems quite strange), still as I suggested in previous paragraph, you can provide skript to -exec which will take care of all decision making)

Comment: By virtue of "find" output, with "foo.sh TEST_3", it's always going to be <$HOME>/TEST/TEST_1A/TEST_2A/TEST_3 removed. If I change my "find" arguments appropriately, to support partial path, then "foo.sh TEST_2B/TEST_3"  SHOULD remove TEST_2B/TEST_3