# Using "find" to filter multiple matches in bash

Tags: regex, bash, find

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix “find” command usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922943/unix-find-command-usage)

This is for a bash installation script. The script foo.sh takes "DIRECTORY" as an argument. Say, there is a dir /TEST/TEST_1A/TEST_2A/TEST_3 and another dir /TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3.

Script: foo.sh in brief.

```
DIR=`find $HOME -type d -name $1 | head 1'
if [ DIR is set to a directory ]
then
rm -rf $DIR
```

**Usage: foo.sh TEST_3**

Now from the script, only the /TEST/TEST_1A/TEST_2A/TEST_3 can be removed. To remove /TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3, I need to use a reg exp in my find command, to fine tune the remove to resolve the directory conflict.

Modified the **find** part of the above script as below

```
DIR='find $HOME -type d -regexp $1 | head 1
```

**NEW Usage: foo.sh TEST_2B/TEST_3**

But "find" command FAILS to get the DIR set to /TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3 and instead returns empty & as a result DIR is empty and I can never ever remove /TEST/TEST_1B/TEST_2B/TEST_3

How do I change the script, so that find can act on JUST the directory name, as well as on the path to the directory too with NO issues. Infact, some users may give a partial directory path as argument to "foo.sh". I expect "foo.sh" to work, even in such cases

Comment: It appears you are freely interchanging `\`` and `'` characters. Is that only in your posting here? Or are your scripts trying to use `'` in place of `\`` characters?

Comment: .. and are you aware of what the `head(1)` command actually _does_?

Comment: you can't specify a subdir/path as you have in your 'NEW Usage section' and expect it to match anything. find searches for file entries in the specified directory structure (whether the file is a real file, or a direcotry. You're asking it to search 2 levels at once. Also are  you saying  you **don't** want to delete both TEST_3 dirs? AND you're sure that the dir you do want to delete will **always** be the first in the list? Better to show us the output (as DIR) from all of your examples. Good luck.

Comment: cm'on @Mike, learn how to edit your first question and not post the same thing more than once. What a waste of effort. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would simply chain it all up:

```
find $HOME -type d -name $1 | grep '\bTEST_.*?A\b' | xargs rm -rf
```

This will delete all directories only if they are on a path that contains "TEST_A"